# implement ray-casting in gazebo9, bumped into multithreading issue

Tags: gazebo-plugin, gazebo-9

Recently, I've been working on a lidar sensor plugin in Gazebo. I'm attempting to initiate a thread within the sensor plugin to continuously execute 'dSpaceCollide2,' but for some reason, it crashes. The following is what I did:

```
void Load(sensors::SensorPtr _parent, sdf::ElementPtr sdf)
{
    // launch a thread to save point cloud
    distortpc_thd = std::make_unique<std::thread>(&DistortPC::DistortPCHandler, this);
}

void DistortPC::DistortPCHandler()
{
    //...
    // here is the operation invoke GetPhysicsUpdateMutex() and dSpaceCollide2()
    laserShape->GetIntersection(dist, entity);
    // ...
}
```

when i launch gazebo, at random time it crashed.
I suspect it's due to multiple threads accessing shared resources. However, when I place this operation in the 'worldUpdateBegin' callback, it works fine.

```
void Load(sensors::SensorPtr _parent, sdf::ElementPtr sdf)
{
    // move thread unsafe ops to event handler, and it works normal!
    update_connection_ = event::Events::ConnectWorldUpdateBegin(
        boost::bind(&DistortPC::DistortPCHandler, this));
```

Yet, I aim to have this operation run continuously rather than waiting for the callback to execute. Could you kindly advise on how to resolve this issue? Or I just want the collison detection like dSpaceCollide2() works instead of the whole physics simulation stuff, how should i disable that? I think only put ray casting on work rather than simulation lower computing load maybe??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gazebo computes physics updates in the same thread as the `worldUpdateBegin`  event, which is why it worked properly when your code was in that callback. Gazebo also uses 3 separate threads for its sensor updates (Cameras/Rendering sensors, CPU-based Ray sensors, and all other sensors: IMU, Force-torque, etc), so there will be thread synchronization issues if you want to access the physics-based collision data from those threads. I don't think there's an easy answer to this.